# Why can't I read a file with Code::Blocks C++?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I've created a file in Code::Blocks called `datos.csv`, and I have this code:

```
std::ifstream file("datos.csv");
if (file) {
    cout << "Managed to read file successfully.";
}else{
    cout << "Unable to read file.";
}
```

But it is unable to read the file.

I tested the same code with TextMate, which can run C++ files, and it was indeed able to read the file, so I suppose there's something up with Code::Blocks. What am I missing?

My file appears listed in "Others" in Code::Blocks' navigator.

Comment: is the csv file inside the same directory?

Answer (score 4):

you need to modify the Target Properties, go to Project -> Properties -> Build targets and change the "Executing Working Dir" for the debug/release folder of your proyect, I hope this help.

Greetings.
Saludos.

Comment: Relative path works for "Execution Working Dir" field. So, if your input file is in project directory, you can just use `.`(Dot).

Answer (score 1):

It can't find the file to open it. Since you are not using absolute paths to open the file it must be relative to the current working directory. If you are launching from the debugger you can set the working directory used when the application is launched. Make sure that directory is the same as where the csv file is located.